# Vue fetch response.json promise not creating reactive getters

Tags: json, typescript, vuejs2, fetch-api

I have a Vue application written with Typescript and I'm using Fetch to retrieve data from an api. In one of my components I have the following interface defined:

```
interface SearchResult {
    device_id: string;
    location: string;
    sub_location: string;
    status: string;
}
```

In my Fetch method I cast the response.json() promise to an array of the SearchResult interface like so:

```
fetch(url).then(response => response.json() as Promise<SearchResult[]>)
          .then(data => { 
              this.results = data; 
          })
```

The issue I have is, if 'status' is not included in the response.json(), no reactive getter is created for `this.results.status`, meaning I can't mutate the data and have it react on the page.

I tried manually setting the value of 'status' after I the line `this.results = data`, and when I inspect the object using VueTools I can see it has the status property with the value I assigned it. But the reactive getter and setter is still missing.

I also tried changing the interface to a class with a constructor that set a default value for 'status', but this also failed to create the reactive getter and setter for the property.

How can I create the reactive getters and setters without explicitly adding 'status' (or any other arbitrary properties) to the api response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) properties added to an object that has already been added to data unless you add the property via `$set`.

Change your fetch response to:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json() as Promise<SearchResult[]>)
  .then(data => { 
    this.results = data; 
    for (let result of this.results)
      this.$set(result, 'status', "some value");
  })
```

Though you should also be able to get away with:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json() as Promise<SearchResult[]>)
  .then(data => { 
    this.results = data.map(d => d.status = "some value"); 
  })
```

Comment: The solution I ended up using was the second suggestion. Because `data` is an array, it was easier to set the property while iterating over it then setting it to `this.results`. The key was to set the properties on the `data` object before assigning it to `this.results`.

Comment: @hackintosh Doh, sorry I didn't notice it was an array. Fairly obvious. I updated the answer.